# Не получается захватить блокировку из другого потока

Tags: c++, многопоточность

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

class A
{
private:
    std::mutex m{};

public:
    void foo()
    {
        for(uint64_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            std::lock_guard lock(m);
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        }
    }

    void pause()
    {
        m.lock();
    }

    void resume()
    {
        m.unlock();
    }
};

int32_t main()
{
    A a;
    std::thread th(&A::foo, &a);
    char ch;
    std::cin >> ch;
    a.pause();
    std::clog << "paused\n";
    std::cin >> ch;
    a.resume();
    th.join();
}
```

Сначала в main() создаётся другой поток, который исполняет A::foo(), внутри A::Foo() поток крутится в цикле for.

В цикле for держится блокировка на мьютекс, однако, после каждой итерации цикла вызывается деструктор от std::lock_guard, который освобождает блокировку. На итерациях цикла поток просто спит(std::this_thread::sleep_for()).

Из основного потока пытаюсь захватить блокировку на мьютекс, вызывая метод A::pause(). Но у A::pause() не получается захватить блокировку вплоть до выхода параллельного потока из цикла for. Почему блокировка не захватывается?

Собирал программу на linux, последний gcc(12.2.0), компилировал так:
g++ -std=c++20 -O3 -s -flto mutex.cpp -Wall -Wextra -Weffc++

Comment: Вызов `unlock` не предполагает автоматического поиска мест, где у этого мьютекса вызывается `lock` с возобновлением вызова. Тут нужна `condition_variable`.

Comment: https://cplusplus.com/reference/mutex/mutex/unlock/
If other threads are currently blocked attempting to lock this same mutex, one of them acquires ownership over it and continues its execution.

Comment: Не стоит пользоваться cplusplus.com

Comment: Всё корректно. "Справедливого" распределения захвата мьютекса стандарт C++ не обещал (как и POSIX, для простых мьютексов по умолчанию). По сути, причиной голодания основного потока является то, что ваша реализация мьютексов оптимизирована для сценария "быстрый захват"/"короткое изменение"/"быстрое освобождение". В вашем случае, если добавить std::this_thread::yield() перед std::lock_guard() вероятность голодания резко снизится. Но если нужны гарантии справедливости или приоритета, то, либо лезть "под капот" в native_handle, либо нужна надстройка с очередью. Но любая "справедливость" - тормоза.

Comment: "...one of them acquires ownership over it and continues its execution..." - забыто условие "если успеет".